# Appium node.js - I want to set a value in the filed and XPath for that particular field is not available. how could I do that

Tags: node.js, webdriver, appium, webdriver-io, appium-android

**Appium node.js**
There is no XPath or accessibility id available for Card Number.

```
 this.selectCard.click(); //This will select (Credit or Debit Card) from brain tree

    //With below code, I want to set the value in the card number field

    onDevice(withText("Card Number")).perform(setText(5555 5555 555 5555 5555));
```

But nothing happens

Comment: you need to share code of the xml, use appium inspector and point to the element you want to get.

Comment: @AdrianJimenez Appium did not fetch any XML code. When it opens the Brain tree. That's why I am stuck on that. ("Card Number") is the **Heading**  and below there is an input field for number. So That's what I am trying to do.

Comment: @ShadowWalker try Uiautomatorviewer if app is native else you can use chrome inspect dev tool

Comment: @Muzzamil Yes I am using both Uiautomatorviewer and Appium but nothing appears. Its mobile app How can I use a chrome inspect dev tool on Android Emulator.

Comment: @ShadowWalker see here all steps mentioned https://www.toolsqa.com/mobile-automation/appium/inspect-elements-of-mobile-web-application/

Comment: are you using java for scripting? I have something that can help to set text/send keys?

Comment: @Muzzamil I am using node.js

Comment: @ShadowWalker Node.js for environment set up but which programming language you are using for writing code/test ? I think it is Java script

Comment: @muzzamil I am using javaScript

Comment: I suggest you to use appium desktop inspector to inspect your element.